# AWS IoT: multiple IoT Registry to split applications

Tags: amazon-web-services, iot, aws-iot

I'm asking how to use the AWS IoT Registry for multiple applications. It would be nice to have one IoT Registry for each product/application, but it seems AWS IoT Registry is unique. For each application there will be hunderds of devices.

The only solution I found is to create a Thing name with an application-dependent prefix: "Product1_id1", "Product1_id2",... "Product2_id1", "Product2_id", ...

Another solution is to create a different AWS account for each application.

It's a very pity AWS doesn't let you create different projects with a separate Registry.

Answer (score 0):

How about use AWS IoT Thing group and type?

ref. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/thing-groups.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/thing-types.html

Comment: Yes, it's possible. However the Registry will be always the same. For example, you can't have two devices, even if with different type and group, with the same name.

Comment: thing name means thing id(=client id). so it must be unique. so what you wrote is only solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently supported.

You can emulate this behavior with ThingGroups, ThingTypes, Thing attributes, and even using Thing Shadows.